# Why doesn't C crash when I malloc wrong amount of memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind, heap-memory

I'm learning C and I'm wondering why the code below didn't crash, I only picked up on the problem using Valgrind.

```
void push(char *element){
  FILE *file = fopen("stack.db", "w");
  int rc = fwrite(element, sizeof(element), 1, file);
  if (file) fclose(file);
}

void top() {
  char *top_element = malloc(sizeof(char));
  FILE *file = fopen("stack.db", "r+");
  int rc = fread(top_element, sizeof(char), 1, file);
  printf("Top element: %s", top_element);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char action = argv[1][0];
  switch (action) {
    case 'p':
      printf("pushing element to stack\n");
      push(argv[2]);
      break;
    case 't':
      top();
      break;
    default:
      printf("die\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

First I call `push()` and write `argv[2]` to the file. Then I call `top()`; I get a piece of memory from malloc, the sizeof char, and assign it to top_element. However, this should be the sizeof char* so I am actually calling `malloc(1)` when I should have been calling `malloc(8)`. This code works and I only picked up on the error when using Valgrind.

My question is, how does it work when the size of memory that I assigned to `top_element` was too small?

Comment: Writing beyond allocated memory is undefined behaviour. Crashing is just one of the possible outcomes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it should be `sizeof(char)`. You want a segment of memory long enough to store a single character; `malloc(sizeof(char))` returns a pointer to exactly that. `malloc(sizeof(char*))` would return a pointer to enough memory to store a `char*`. You can think of `malloc(T * n)` as returning a `T*` to `n` `T`s.

I suspect Valgrind is complaining that `printf` is going to read beyond the end of the string *represented* by the `char* top_element`, as it's not zero terminated. If you want to read a string of `n` bytes from a file, you do need `n + 1` bytes of memory, as you need to account for the `\0` you should place on the end. However, not all `char*`'s represent strings, so this usage is fine in many cases. In your case, it *really* should be:

```
// Allocate zeroed memory
char *top_element = calloc(2, sizeof(char));

if (top_element)
{
  FILE *file = fopen("stack.db", "r+");
  int rc = fread(top_element, sizeof(char), 1, file);
  printf("Top element: %s", top_element);
  free(top_element);
}
else
{
  // Out of memory!
}
```

Comment: also there is a memory leak here as top_element never gets freed

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. Great answer and explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about `char *` and `char`:
A `char` can contain a character (duh!), while a `char *` is a pointer to a character. A pointer to a character *can* also be a *string*, but it doesn't *have* to be. A *string* is a number of consecutive `char`s, terminated by a null-byte.

> char *top_element = malloc(sizeof(char));

Asks `malloc()` for memory to store a single `char`, not a string.

> printf("Top element: %s", top_element);

Tells `printf()` to expect a string. 
Since `top_element` really is just a `char`, it needs not be null-terminated. If it isn't, `printf()` will read past the allocation, which is undefined behaviour (if you're lucky, `printf()` will hit a page boundary to an unallocated page, causing a page-fault).
The reason that you've not crashed is that uninitialised memory will *often* contain zero-bytes, which will act like the null-terminator for `printf()`. This is not guaranteed however, and relying on it would be very dangerous.

Comment: I did sort of understand this but I guess its quite confusing in practice. You explanation is very clear and helped me understand it better. Thanks